# Making multiple branches in make_branch function of Cplex

Tags: cplex, callback

In my current python code, I have used MyBranch call back of Cplex to make 2 branches and solve my model.

However, I now need to generate 4 branches after the first incumbent is generated. I need advise if this is possible, and if yes, how it that executed.

Comment: This is just partial info, that you may be able to use: this was not possible with the legacy callbacks. But you could work around it by adding a node info-object. First you create two nodes each containing the search space of two of the nodes you want to end up with. Next, when you select these new nodes in the B&B tree, you have attached an info-object telling you how to split the node so it ends up as you intended in the first place

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Sune. So does that mean, at one time only single node is searched out of the two you suggested to generate? I have a similar framework right now but this takes longer to solver than expected.

Comment: No, both nodes would get scrutinized eventually. You could consider it to be delayed branching.

Comment: I have an almost decade-old [blog post](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2012/06/birthing-litter-in-cplex.html) about this. It matches the comment from @Sune.

Comment: Thanks Sune, I am trying to reduce time to solve by multiple branches here. I will try node info-object though. Thanks prubin, I will go through the blog post.